# How to suppress Inspection of JavaScript code block in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: javascript, typescript, intellij-idea, eslint, code-analysis

I've run Inspect Code on a JavaScript file in IntelliJ IDEA. I'm presented with options to Suppress for statement or Suppress for file, but I need to suppress for a block of code. I tried wrapping `/* eslint-disable */` and `/* eslint-enable */` around the block of code, but that didn't work.

Comment: See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/disabling-and-enabling-inspections.html#suppress-inspections
What is your use-case? Share a problematic code sample

Comment: I have source code embedded in my JavaScript file that have many warnings but need to remain unedited. I don't want to disable inspections for the entire file so the best thing to do is suppress warnings on the block of embedded code. Eslint supports this use case [link](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/rules#disabling-rules)